# why is ninjectwebcommon.cs no longer included with nuget package Ninject for MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

Why is ninjectwebcommon.cs no longer included with the nuget package for MVC 5 in visual studio?

My concern is, I want to know how to configure ninject properly for use in MVC and in WebApi. However, I was disappointed that there was nothing on http://www.ninject.org/

and on the github project for it  an issue got opened and closed without this being resolved ( https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/issues/35 ) and no info about how to configure the package.

I know you can hunt around the web and find some config. But the problem with that is that you don't know if you are picking up good practice or not.

I don't understand why the creators of the ninject package are hiding this info from us.
Indeed I asked the question on http://www.ninject.org/ via the speakup option and received no answer.

Am I missing something obvious here or is everyone searching for an answer for this and just pulling in random findings from the web into their projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this documentation. There are all informations needed to fix this. https://github.com/SkydivingAngel/Ninject-WebApi-2-and-Mvc5

Edit: Look exactly into Readme.md file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did manage to find a sample ninjectwebcommon.cs file by doing a web search. However, my concern is that I should not have to do this - ninject should provide guidance on how to do this on their website and within their nuget package. They used to do this in earlier versions of the package but no longer do this. This means users new to the package have to hunt round for some config and hope they stumble on a good one. I just want to know why ninject.org don't provide any help with this out of the box when you install their packages.